# PHP password hash not the same when registering and logging in

Tags: php

When a user registers and logs in, I use the same password_hash function to hash the plain-text password.

`password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`

However the password is not the same.

I can prove this another way by simply registering two users with the same password.

For example "admin" turns into "$2y$10$SyqILazLbo4jJVYvxYfwW.WgHUnSi.cRMETWoMjZXwMNa4H4tYELK"

on one user, and "$2y$10$gXfVz6oH4afxAL.7ytFJseZV3VERxbSYXqN7FYsRzH4IrjJw9uyO6" on another. This means the password_hash will never be the same, so user cann ever log in.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's normal since that function will produce a different hash each time. Now why are you saying what seems to be that can they *never* log in?

Comment: To log in, the user supplies their username, and password. The password must be hashed in the database, so.. username must = username. password must = password. How will the passwords ever be equal if the hash is different each time?

Comment: that's just how the function works, so don't worry about it.

Comment: .... user registers "admin" as pw. This is saved as "admin123" with hash (pretend). User logins with "admin" as pw. This is hashed as "admin456". admin123 != admin456. User will never log in.

Comment: **Show us how you are using** `password_verify()` to check the passord

Comment: sorry, but with what you just said, I really don't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you. was not aware of this. I thought you just compare the hashes and you win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `password_verify` for verifying if password is correct or not. Something like this

```
<?php

$password = "rasmuslerdorf";

$hash =  password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
  echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
  echo 'Invalid password.';
}

?>
```

[reference page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the function `password_verify($user_submitted_password, $hash_in_db)` to check the result.
`password_hash()` embeds a random salt in each hashing, that's why the key is different but it will verify correctly.

See the example in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) of `password_verify()`

```
<?php
// See the password_hash() example to see where this came from.
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>
```